# Can't mount samba drive

Tags: mount, samba, ftp, shared-folders, cifs

I have a shared HDD connected to my Asus router.
I can't access the ftp in nautilus by ftp://192.168.1.1/My_DRIVE
The problem come when I want to mount the drive at boot. This goes to /etc/fstab

```
//192.168.1.1/My_DRIVE/ /mnt/FTP cifs credentials=/home/user/.ftp_credentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,vers=1.0 0 0
```

I got the following error

> Retrying with upper case share name
>
> mount error(6): No such device or address
>
> Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Comment: I'm confused. Everything about your post implies you are trying to connect via ftp yet your fstab is using cifs. If in fact you are trying to access by ftp and connecting by nautilus DOES work I would suggest using the package: gigolo to automount. Either way pleace make clear if this is a cifs question or an ftp question.

Comment: @Morbius1 Ok, this is nice. Thank you for you'r response. But I thinks is not what I want. I want to mount the shared HDD as system partition, some program doesn't work other way

Comment: I found a solution, but not complete

`sudo curlftpfs -o allow_other user:password@address/My_Drive /mnt/FTP/`


but how I can mount at system boot ?